# Sort table by the first record of many-many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have:

```
Book
  has_many :book_authors
  has_many :authors, through: :book_authors

BookAuthor
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :book

Author
  has_many :book_authors
```

So I can list books with multiple authors

[image: books list]

I want to sort books by the first name of the first author.

[image: sorted by first author name]

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are using.

Comment: If possible, rethink the database design. Having an `Authors` column with multiple names is going to make life difficult for you. A better design would have a separate column for the first name, surname and patronymic (if it exists) of the author, and then a many-to-many relationship between authors and books.

Comment: You do state that you want to sort by the first author's name. However, it isn't normal to sort by first names. You would want to sort by the author's surname instead, and then it becomes less straight-forward, using the design you have.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I use Ruby on Rails with it's ORM and actually I simplified the problem here because the original query is very complicated with polimorphism and so on.

Comment: What does the table-schema look like for the relevant tables, or do you have no control over that?

Comment: @PiotrBrudny I assume you are maintaining separate table for each author by the design.But you want to fetch book authors as combined result.is it?

Comment: @krishnar Yes. That is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate function on Author `name` column:

```
Book.left_outer_joins(:authors).group("books.id").order("MIN(authors.name)")
```

`@Pragash`'s solution, which is `Book.joins(:authors).order('authors.name desc')` will return the same books many times if they have many authors. Using `.distinct` however will return unique books.

```
Book.left_outer_joins(:authors).order('authors.name').distinct
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work only if all the books have an author. Otherwise the books without the author won't appear

```
Book.joins(:authors).order('authors.name desc')
```

Comment: But this is going to return the same book many times if it has many authors. You also need to use `distinct` to fetch each book once

Answer (score 1):

You would take the query you have and add:

```
order by authors
```

That will order by the first name of the first author in the list.